# MariaDB/mysqld is blocked by `docker-default` AppArmor profile

Tags: docker, mariadb, apparmor

I had a working MySQL install and I tried to migrate it to MariaDB. I also have Docker, which seems to block /usr/sbin/mysqld via AppArmor.

To be clear, I’m not using Docker currently (but I’d like to not have to remove it since I will be using it soon).

The problem I’m having is when I’m trying to load my project, served by good old Apache, in the browser. I’m getting a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` error message.

The workaround right now is to force AppArmor to unblock mysqld:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld && sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

This *works*, but I have to redo it after every system boot.

`aa-status` clearly shows who the culprit is:

```
4 processes are in enforce mode.
   ...
   /usr/sbin/mysqld (2960) docker-default
```

After running the workaround above, this line disappears from `aa-status` and everything works perfectly.

How can I permanently disable this "protection" from the `docker-default` profile?

Comment: mariadb is not a drop-in replacement for mysql, the incompatible differences section of the mariadb manual is now several pages long.

Comment: Yes, that’s why I said "supposed." The thing is, it seems like it’s very hard or impossible to just install MariaDB *next to* MySQL, which is what I thought was going to happen when running `apt install mariadb-client mariadb-server`. Instead I got a broken install :)
Edit: I’ll update the first sentence of my question since I might have chosen the wrong words there.

Comment: I understand at least two people have voted for closing the question. Genuinely interested in what’s wrong about it, is is off-topic, or too vague?

Comment: I would venture judging from the close reason that they thought this question was off topic for SO as it is not about software development, but about server configuration / software installation.

Comment: Could be! I’m really not sure where is the best place for this kind of question. Server Fault? DevOps? Super User? Unix & Linux? There is significante overlap between all these, if you ask me.

Comment: Serverfault or DBA sister sites of SO seem to be better suited. I would remove the question from here and ask it on one of the two sites.

Comment: [ref](https://lucascavalare.github.io/2020-03-15-AppArmor_Docker/) and [ref2](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33060#issuecomment-419363270). Info like docker version, distro version, and perhaps even MariaDB version (distro or from upstream) would be useful